# Информация к размышлению о деструктивном влиянии Stack Overflow

Tags: обсуждение

Вот такая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/319276/) на Хабре, в которой речь идет и о нас :) -

> Чтобы получить ответы, программисты девяностых читали исходники и руководства. Программисты двухтысячных начали активно гуглить. А затем в 2008 появился Stack Overflow, и стал «внешней памятью» для разработчиков. Теперь на 95% вопросов есть готовый ответ: первая ссылка из гугла на Стек.
>
> Вроде бы это хорошо: не надо полдня разбираться в причинах. Скопировал решение, вставил, работаем дальше. Но плохо то, что внешние решения проходят мимо головы. Когда человек в следующий раз столкнется с той же проблемой, он снова полезет на Стек. И снова. И снова.
>
> Чужое решение не запоминается. Нет стимула разбираться, как оно устроено. Нет чувства удовлетворения, когда «заработало!». Не образуются в мозгу новые нейронные связи. А без этого нет и запоминания.
>
> Дальше хуже. Когда злоупотребляешь готовыми ответами, перестаешь воспринимать аналогии и косвенные решения. Ищешь, чтобы прямо один-в-один было то, что тебе нужно. В долгой перспективе это тупик.

Не то чтобы спрашиваю - каждый решает сам для себя. Но, разжевывая до конца, до полной мелочи ответы на *достаточно простые вопросы* - не приносим ли мы этим вред? Вопросы, где достаточно потратить минут 20, чтобы разобраться - пусть даже просто написать несколько тестов и посмотреть, как оно работает. Речь не о явном выполнении домашек, а там, где, похоже, человеку даже в Гугл лень полезть и поискать?

[image: кафедра гугления]

Comment: Ура, как же долго я ждал единомышленника :)

Comment: Публикация по ссылке – полная чушь. Совет его автору – капнуть еще лет на 20 назад, когда и Google еще не было. Пусть идет в библиотеку и ищет ответ по алфавитному указателю. Stack Overflow – повышает доступность информации. Когда мне надо было написать [тестовый сервер](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_question_association), я сделал это за 30 минут! 7 лет назад, мне бы потребовалось дня два, 20 лет назад – несколько недель.

Comment: Если автор поста на указанном ресурсе не удосуживается разобраться в том, что он делает – это личное упущение. Я рад, что есть Stack Overflow, так как реальные примеры кода позволяют понять проблемы и быстрее и глубже.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А вы точно уверены, что 7 и 20 лет назад вы обладали той же квалификацией, что и сегодня?...

Comment: @Harry 20 лет назад, если честно, я умел не многое (от слова «совсем»), но 7 лет назад я имел более или менее сравнимую квалификацию. Как раз в это время и запустили SOru. Зачем? Потому что найти любую информацию было крайне сложно, я лично у себя на ПК хранил файлик с задачками и решениями к ним. Информацию надо было не просто найти, но и выдрать ее, к примеру, из чьей–то почтовой переписки выложенной в сеть.

Comment: @Other Ну, как минимум, я стараюсь по мере возможности дать ответ либо разъясняющий - что да как, или намекающий - а попробуй так... а представь, что... Правда, далеко не всегда это удается - часто куда проще дать готовый код :(

Comment: Вроде тут так не принято (пометка о неполном ответе), но всё упирается в одно - популярность. Доходы ли, top PR ли, ЧСВ ли - не суть, главное чтобы было много посетителей. А значит нужно разжевать и в ответ положить. А песни о "великом благе", "единой базе" (тут, правда, есть смысл, но его убивают тупыми вопросами) и подобном - просто прикрытие.

Answer (score 9):

Моя позиция: **такие пользователи ответов имеют полное право вредить самим себе, осознают они это или же нет**. Я же со своей стороны стараюсь сообщать в ответах о потенциальных подводных камнях, связанных с применением моих решений. Они же оставляют за собой право не читать предупреждений и страдать от последствий.

---

*Вот вам неожиданная параллель:*

## Профессионалы из нашей среды занимаются тем же!

(Просто носитель отличается.)

> Чужое решение не запоминается. Нет стимула разбираться, как оно устроено. Нет чувства удовлетворения, когда «заработало!». Не образуются в мозгу новые нейронные связи. А без этого нет и запоминания.

Вы видите здесь описание проблемы. А я вижу здесь описание процесса использования **отлично спроектированной библиотеки** (пакета, модуля, и т. п.). Вполне конкретный признак: **вам не нужно знать, что внутри, чтобы этим воспользоваться**.

И мы, индустрия, стараемся наращивать базу таких решений в разных менеджерах пакетов, репозиториях, каталогах, да хотя бы просто на гитхабе. И сами же пишем инструкции по их использованию.

Посему предлагаю рассмотреть немножко перенаправленный вопрос:

### Несёт ли вред публикация кода решений часто возникающих проблем (для примера, на том же гитхабе)?

Напрашивается ответ **нет**, т. к. это вроде и есть одно из главных направлений деятельности любого разработчика.

С другой стороны, слепо полагаться на чужое решение ненадёжно, и его всё равно стоит изучить. Кто этого не делает — рискует. Риск, в зависимости от ситуации (авторов решения, квалификации автора, [не-]возможности ПО нанести реальный ущерб), может быть и не быть оправданным.

Но вернёмся к StackOverflow и ответам.

Каждый такой ответ с "разовым решением" можно считать маленьким программным продуктом, библиотечкой, весь исходный код которой (как правило) содержится прямо в ответе вместе со всей  документацией. (Хотя в мире NPM вроде не возбраняется даже такую мелочь публиковать в формате пакетов [вспоминаем эпичную историю про `left-pad`], формат SO мне нравится немножко больше.)

---

*Ну, и из более общих доводов, такими ответами мы открываем новые возможности большему кругу лиц, экономим время другим людям, снижаем порог вхождения<s>, бла-бла-бла, это понятно и не так интересно.</s>*

Answer (score 9):

**Для кого-то, задача может быть тривиальна, а для кого-то – нет** Например, для новичка, убрать из строки пробелы и заменить все строчные на заглавные - это пара часов "въезжания" в тему и инструменты, изучение стандартных библиотек по работе со строками и куча граблей.

Не стоит забывать, что когда-то даже самые умные программисты были новичками (и не знали *как* хранятся строки и что такое "алгоритмы").

На такие *простые* вопросы **вредно отвечать куском кода** "на отвали", это лишь потешит ваше ЧСВ, но реально мало кому поможет. Лучше пройти мимо, если нету настроения объяснить.

Comment: Речь не об уровне вопроса. Но когда человек спрашивает, какая библиотечная функция выполняет поиск в строке или позиционирование в файле - это уже просто лень.

Comment: @Harry я попытался это раскрыть в первом абзаце. Вспомните себя, вы же не всегда знали что такое библиотека, и что такое позиционирование в файле и что они вообще *так* работают. Мы с вами уже давно привыкли, что наши мозги *так* работают, понимая все эти концепции на подсознательном уровне.

Comment: Конечно, не всегда. Но у меня была по тем временам пара неплохих книг - тогда и началось активное изучение английского, потому как книги в основном были не на русском - и неуемное желание знать и понимать. Чего, откровенно говоря, мало вижу сейчас - не здесь даже, в реальной жизни, например, глядя на своего малого. Меня тогда злила каждая программа, если она делала что-то, что я в принципе не знал, как можно воспроизвести :) Да, тогда был FidoNet и SU.C_CPP :), но куда большую информацию по азам я получал из просмотра заголовочных файлов и чтения хелпов. Каковые есть и сейчас.

Comment: Вот, не далее как сегодня утром отвечал про позиционирование в файле на C++. Интереса ради сейчас сделал поиск - специально туповатый "*как перейти в файле в нужную позицию C++*" - и 4-м пунктом получил очень приличные "Лекции по C/C++: работа с файлами (stdio.h)". Неужели это **дольше**, чем набрать вопрос и ждать неизвестно сколько времени ответа? Неужели - опять же конкретный вопрос - получив четкое сообщение компилятора о том, что такой-то заголовок должен быть включен раньше - надо просто тупо сбрасывать пару килобайт ошибок и вопрошать - что тут происходит? Регулярно идут вопросы,

Comment: когда берешь код, компилируешь - и получаешь ответ от компилятора на ВСЕ заданные человеком вопросы. Не знаю, мне казалось, что здесь - ultima ratio, когда ничего не получается, когда или вопрос выше твоей компетенции настолько, что не понимаешь даже, что искать, или когда да, бывает - замылился глаз настолько, что не видишь очевидного. Но это сразу видно, когда человек долго бьется. Понимаете, так RuSO теряет главное - **профессионализм**. И становится просто бесплатным филиалом какого-нибудь Reshaem.net... Получается, что профессионалы не воспитывают профессионалов, а скатываются до чайников

Comment: @Harry вот чтобы такого не было, следует закрывать *такие* вопросы и не давать *такие* ответы (свежий пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614586)

Answer (score 4):

Автор конечно однобоко подал материал, но затронул больную тему.
Люди разные. Один развивается в постоянном общении, другой всё ищет сам в исходниках Один по поводу и без повода, ну удосужившись подумать пять минут бежит на форумы писать, а другой задаёт вопрос только после тщательного поиска информации на тему. Это распространяется не только на программирование, но и на всю жизнь. Ярким примером могут служить рефераты в школе. Один скачает, поправит слова и готово, другой скрупулёзно разрабатывает тему. То что более доступным стал один из методов не умаляет значимость второго. 
Статья - затравка с громким заголовком.

Разверну ещё тему. Есть те кто откровенно паразитирует. Т.е. кинули вопрос, а сами занимаются другими делами, пусть другие на меня поработают...
Иное дело когда вопрос скорее концептуальный, ответ на который не найти в манах и если нужен не столько ответ, сколько мнение вот здесь и сейчас. Иные кидают вопросы ради придания себе чувства некоей значительности "вот я какой крутой, на SO меня знают. Я вот задал вопрос довольно простой, и, к своему стыду, почти сразу после отправки увидел на него ответ. Тоже вариант. Пока формулируешь вопрос сам формируешь новые ответы. Так что просто ещё один инструмент появился.

Что до мнения системы... Каждый учится для себя. И потому как раньше так и сейчас часто диплом даже не смотрят. Но не стоит так уж с ненавистью смотреть на плагиатчиков и халявщиков. В бизнесе нужны разные умения. Где-то добротная уникальная разработка, а где-то умение заткнуть дыру с максимальной скоростью с приемлемым заказчику качеством. И не факт что трудяги на такое хорошо способны. Жулики тоже нужны :)

Тут ведь ещё какое дело. Нужно быть достаточно квалифицированным что бы понять что тебе посоветовали, понять что посоветовали именно то. И вопрос нужно задать уметь. Тоже умение очень и очень полезное.

Comment: Просто у меня чтение статьи совпало с [вопросом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613996/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%A1), ответ на который есть в любом "С++ для чайников". По мне - классика, человек не то что в книгу - в Гугл не глянул, сразу сюда...

Comment: @Harry В этом нет ничего плохого! Более того, [вопрос, показатель истинного интереса к профессии](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/6).

Comment: *Один скачает, поправит слова и готово* -- беда в том, что "общественная система" в этом случае будет считать, что он разрабатывал эту тему и освоил её. Но к ещё большему сожалению, мнению "общественной системы" из-за этого верят не меньше. [[meta-tag:нытьё]]